# llamar archivos desde el mismo modulo

Tags: nodejs, npm

Hola hace un momento vi en un repositorio que que podía llamar en la misma carpeta del proyecto subcarpetas o archivos que estuvieran declarados en el `package.json` mediante `@declaracion: file: nombrearchivo`  creo haberlo visto en varios lados mas pero no le di importancia, ahora he querido buscar como funciona pero no encuentro esto en los docs de nodejs y tampoco en los de npm 
entonces dos cosas uno explicarme el funcionamiento y dos pasarme el enlace de la documentación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya encontré la documentación en `npm` casi no la encuentro esta [aqui](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json)
nunca había utilizado de esta forma pero si conocía que se puede también cargar desde **github** un repositorio, la explicación es la siguiente

```
// package.json
dependencies: {
'@milibreria': 'file:./milibreria'
}
//node
// cuando se require
const milibreria =require('@milibreria')
```

En mi caso note que debía tener otro archivo `package.json` con el nombre que coloque en el `package.json` principal y luego dar `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

El proceso para instalar un **paquete** de npm es:

1. Si no tienes npm iniciado en el proyecto: `npm init` (se creará el package.json)
2. Para instalar un módulo npm subido al repo oficial de npm:

   `npm install --s nombre-del-modulo` (para instalación local en el proyecto)
3. Automáticamente se escribirá en el package.json la dependencia con ese módulo, para que al realizar `npm install` (por ejemplo cuando clonas un proyecto) se instalen automáticamente todos los módulos existentes en dependencies del package.json

Espero que te sirva, un saludo

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta pero es diferente, lo que quería decir era un sub proyecto de mi proyecto y no de uno ya publicado